# simulate dialog exit

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, sendmessage

How would one use SendMessage() or PostMessage() function to close an application, given that the appropriate window handle is retrieved? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the [PostQuitMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644945%28VS.85%29.aspx) function which will post a WM_QUIT message for you.

Comment: How does the application know which app to close (I don't see a HWND parameter in this function)?